# Is that possible to retrieve tweet's from more then one specific account via Twitter API?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I know that i can get tweet from specific account with the help of "**From:User**" but i want to retrieve tweet's from more then one account how can i archive that in node.js ?

i've tried the Boolean search operators and the "separated by comma" (ex. From:User,User ) but did't got any luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get live tweets up to 5000 users with the stream API and the "follow" parameter :
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter.html

To code in node, you can use this package :
https://github.com/ttezel/twit

Here is a full nodejs code to get tweets from @realDonaldTrump and @CNN when they tweet :

```
var Twit = require('twit')

var users = [
    '25073877', // @realDonaldTrump
    '759251' // @CNN
    ];

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         '...',
    consumer_secret:      '...',
    access_token:         '...',
    access_token_secret:  '...'
    });

var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: users }) 
stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
    if(!users.includes(tweet.user.id_str)) {return;}
    console.log(tweet.user.screen_name + ': ' +  tweet.text);
    });
```

Comment: i tried the **follow parameter** but it retrieve all tweet include if some buddy retweet or mention the user name. i don't want to retrieve all tweet's.  i want to retrieve only what the user tweet's.

Comment: Then you can skip tweets from users you are not tracking. I added a full sample code.