# Twitter returns error 401 on tracking multiple ids

Tags: node.js, twitter

When I track single id using this code snippet

```
var stream = Twitter.stream('statuses/filter', { follow : '713445685429932032' });
stream.on('tweet', function (tweet, err) {
    console.log(tweet);
})
```

I can successfully follow the twitter id however if I try to follow list of ids

```
var stream = Twitter.stream('statuses/filter', { follow : ['713445685429932032', '23424']});
stream.on('tweet', function (tweet, err) {
    console.log(tweet);
})
```

I get response status code `401`, as per my understanding twitter allows us to track 5000 ids and I am unable to track even two what appears to be the problem. 
I am using twitter node js module.

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089183/is-that-possible-to-retrieve-tweets-from-more-then-one-specific-account-via-twi/50090316#50090316